# WPF - Where to add CRUD actions in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm new to WPF and I'm trying to implement MVVM model into my WPF application. I have this scenario: a Customers model, a customer view, a CUstomersViewModel and a Dbcontext class.

Model Customers.cs

```
 public partial class Customers
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Customer { get; set; }     
 }
```

MyDbContext.cs

```
 public partial class MyDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext()
        {
        }

        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Customers> Customers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Users> Users{ get; set; }



        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                   // ..............
            }
        }
```

CustomersViewModel.cs

```
 class CustomersViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Customers> Customers { get; set; }

        public CustomersViewModel()
        {

            using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
            {
                Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customers>(db.Customers.ToList());
            }
        }
    }
```

In my view I'm binding the ViewModel to a combobox:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ViewModels:CustomersViewModel x:Key="CustomerViewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>
...

  <ComboBox x:Name="cboCustomers" Grid.Row="2" 
                          DataContext="{StaticResource CustomerViewModel}" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" 
                          DisplayMemberPath="Customer"/>
```

This works fine. However (this might be a silly question), if I want to add more queries, such as retrieve customers by Id, grouping customers by a certain column or update a customer, where would I need to add these?

```
   Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customers>(db.Customers.Where(....))..
```

In the Viewmodel class?  The constructor of the ViewModel, at the moment, gets all customers.

Comment: Create an new class, e.g DBLayer class where you will have all these methods. Have your ViewModel instantiate one object of this class and use its methods when needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I want to add more queries, such as retrieve customers by Id, grouping customers by a certain column or update a customer, where would I need to add these?

For example in a service that you inject the view model with, e.g.:

```
class CustomersViewModel
{
    private readonly ICustomerService _customerService;

    public ObservableCollection<Customers> Customers { get; set; }

    public CustomersViewModel(ICustomerService customerService)
    {
        _customerService = customerService;
    }
}
```

The view model can then invoke operations on the service based on user interactions such as for example button clicks.

The service implementation is responsible for connecting to the database, for example using Entity Framework through a data access layer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I've created the service with all the methods I need but I'm still unsure how to invoke these methods from the ViewModel. Could you please show me an example of how to do this?

Comment: @Leño77: You just call a method of the service using the reference that the view model is injected with, e.g. `_customerService.GetCustomers()`. Where and when to do this is another topic but to translate your original code sample, you would do it in the constructor.